# inserting a data to a gridpane in another fxml file

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml, fxmlloader

my first fxml (button) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<StackPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="fxml_grid_test.fxml_gridtest_controller" >
    <Button fx:id="insertBut" text="insert" onMouseClicked="#insertData"/>
</StackPane>
```

my second fxml (gridpane) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="fxml_grid_test.fxml_gridtest_controller"> 
    <top>
        <GridPane fx:id="gpane">
        </GridPane>
    </top>
</BorderPane>
```

my controller :

```
package fxml_grid_test;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class fxml_gridtest_controller extends Application {

   @FXML private Button insertBut;
    @FXML private GridPane gpane;

    @FXML private void insertData() throws IOException{
        gpane.add(new Label("test"), 0, 0);
        Stage primaryStage = new Stage();

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("grid_fxml.fxml"));
                         Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 350);
                             primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                                primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

my main :

```
package fxml_grid_test;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Fxml_grid_test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("button_fxml.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);

        primaryStage.setTitle("insert data test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

the idea is : 
when i pressed the button, i want to insert some data to my gridpane , and then show the fxml.
both of my fxml share the controller, i feel this is the root of the problem, but i dont know how to solve it.

Comment: Adding dynamic data to a GridPane on the click of a button is possible. But, I am not sure what you are trying to do here. Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add it to your question.

Comment: simply put, i have 2 fxml (fxml_1 and fxml_2)
in fxml_1, i have a button, and in fxml_2 i have a gridpane.

when i pressed the button , i want to insert some data to my gridpane in fxml_2 and then show the fxml.

Comment: Yes that is achievable. Although if you can provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it can be easier to explain.

Comment: As a name implies, the "sqlexception" is not JabaFX related error. Add the stacktrace of that exception and change the question's tag accordingly. By the way what do you mean by " ... so i decided to try it manually"? What did you do manually?

Comment: i've added the simpler code . hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: @Jason Why does both your FMXL have the same controller ?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha sry, totally forgot edit exists :D ,

because i wont doing anything with my second fxml, except just showing the gridpane, 
i feel this is the root of the problem , but i dont know how to solve it.

Comment: @Jason Please edit the question and delete the answer that you have added. It will confuse the future readers.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha ok, done sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controllers are compiled class that implement the "code behind" the object hierarchy defined by the fxml. These are useful to define methods which manipulate the UI elements and can be called by other classes, if necessary.

In your case, we need to define a controller for the `grid.fxml` because we want to create a method which will be responsible for adding elements to the grid.This method will be called in the `MainController`, which is responsible for loading `grid.fxml` and updating it.

[FXMLLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html) helps us to get an instance of the controller which is being referenced in the fxml.

So, you can have two different controllers for each of your fxml file. For the fxml with button, lets call the controller as `ParentController` since it is responsible for loading the sencond fxml.

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class ParentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button insertButton;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }

    @FXML
    private void insertData() throws IOException {
        Stage newStage = new Stage();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("gridpane.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        //Get controller instance from the FXMLLoader
        GridPaneController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.updateGridPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 350);
        newStage.setScene(scene);
        newStage.show();
    }
}
```

As you can see, we are fetching the controller instance and then trying to call a method in the GridPaneController class.

```
GridPaneController controller = loader.getController();
controller.updateGridPane();
```

This `updateGridPane()` contains the logic for updating your `GridPane`, if you need something to be set on the GridPane, you can include parameters to the method and use them.

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class GridPaneController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private GridPane gpane;

    public void updateGridPane() {
        Label newLabel = new Label("test");
        gpane.add(newLabel, 0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }
}
```

The FXML does nothing special, it just have different controllers.

**grid.fxml**

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="fxml_grid_test.GridPaneController">
  <top>
    <GridPane fx:id="gpane">
    </GridPane>
  </top>
</BorderPane>
```

**main.fxml**

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<StackPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="fxml_grid_test.ParentController" >
    <Button fx:id="insertButton" text="insert" onMouseClicked="#insertData"/>
</StackPane>
```

Comment: thank you sir, it works perfectly,
if u dont mind, can u explain simply what initializable is used for ?

Comment: To override the `initialize()`. This method is called once on an implementing controller when the contents of its associated document have been completely loaded and is used to perform any necessary post-processing on the content.